# update chart before the button click event finishes

Tags: jquery, charts

I am trying to get the updated chart image (chart js) when the button is clicked. Here is the button click event :

```
$('.downloadPDF').click(function () {
bar_chart.data.datasets[0].data = avgData;
            bar_chart.data.datasets[1].data = highestData;
            
            bar_chart.update();
```

This chart has a onComplete event on which the source of the image is changed

```
function done() {
    
    var url = $("#divHidden canvas").get(0).toDataURL("image/jpg");
    $("#divHidden img").attr("src", url);
}
```

The problem is the chart + the image get updated only AFTER the button click event finishes. Is there a way I can get the updated image src just after the line bar_chart.update(); ?

What I am trying to do is generate a PDF out of HTML page, for this I am using dinktopdf which is working fine but it does not support CANVAS tags, so have to first save the chart image and then generate the pdf referencing this new image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to wait for the chart to update before you can get the updated image, and the only way to know when the chart is finished updating is to listen for the `onComplete` event. when / where do you generate the pdf?

Comment: @WhiteHat thanks for getting back. I have got it to work but in a clumsy way. I use a onmouseover event of the button to trigger the chart update, and then on click of button I fetch the base64String of the image do a post where I save the image on server. Then within the first post's Success method I do another post to an api action method to genreate a PDF and once done I get back the pdf url and open it up in a new window.... phew

Comment: will you please share the client side code for all of that? otherwise, it will be difficult to provide any assistance...